# Swift form sheet on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to show a simple form sheet on iPhone.

something like this http://static.squarespace.com/static/53449ac2e4b0233041dcf674/t/53937548e4b0c79f2b9b6fb7/1402172750607/TableView.gif?format=500w

I dont wanna use container view though, it shouldn't be that complicated it is just a popover screen that in the middle of the screen with transparent background

However even though I do these steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

`performSegueWithIdentifier("formSheet", sender: self)`

form sheet view controller still shown as full screen like a modal view controller.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation,

> The presentation style determines how a modally presented view controller is displayed on the screen. On iPhone and iPod touch devices, modal view controllers are always presented full-screen, but on iPad devices there are several different presentation options. For a list of possible presentation styles, and their compatibility with the available transition styles, see the “UIModalPresentationStyle” constant descriptions.

Thus, you will not be able to show a Form Sheet on an iPhone, unless you use some third-party library to achieve the same effect. Here is one such library: [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController).

See the [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) for more information.